# How to get text out of div class tag in selenium webdriver?

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver

```
<div class="error-text">invalid login or password.</div>
```

HOw do I retrieve the actual text "invalid login or password"? I m running the test on testNG.
Here is my test java code:

```
WebElement wrong_message = firefox.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/div[3]"));
      System.out.println("message is here:" + wrong_message.getText().toString());
      Assert.assertNotNull(wrong_message);
```

But the output of testrun has empty string instead of "invalid login or password".

Comment: Are you sure it is div[3]? And how is related to id='login-form'? Post more related HTML

Comment: Have you tried using xpath?

Comment: Very little `html` in order to understand what's going on. And, can you not use `class` ?

Answer (score 3):

Html code for your sample is missing so by what I understand of the structure of the page I would suggest:

```
WebElement wrong_message =
firefox.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()[contains(.,'invalid')]]"));
```

This way it will extract the text from the div only if it contains the string "invalid"